# How to get an iOS app build for appium testing?

Tags: ios, xcode, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

I wanted to setup iOS testing on simulator on my MacBook-pro. Im using appium 1.6 and Xcode 8 and iOS 10.1 as simulator OS. I ran my appium server and set the desired capabilities and used an .ipa from the app store and it crashes on launch while doing an inspect on appium. Is it happening because i don't have a app signed for development?  what are the requirements for the app to be tested for using? Do i need signed apps to be used for testing on simulator too ?

Comment: this video will help you, : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySglJIrDVMQ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a .app file useing the belowing instruction:

1- Go to:

```
xcode > File > New Project > (select ios at top bar) select Tabbed Application > click Next > give project name and select swift as language and complete process.
```

2- Open the project and run it. After running the app in the simulator, you will find the project .app file in the product folder (expand your project in xcode > product.

you can use this .app file for your appium test.

3- You can also get a lot of free .xcode project on the web. download this project, open the .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace file in xcode and run it. you will find the .app file in the product folder

if you want to run your ios app in the simulator, you need a .app file, not .ipa file. The .ipa file runs on the device. Try to generate a .app file for simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need apps to be signed with a developer provisiioning profile. You can use the [iresign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign) to do it. you should input your ipa file developer provisioning file(contact your dev) and click resign. It will output the resigned app

The same dev provisioning file, dev certificate should be installed in your mac from where you run your scripts.

**Note**: you cannot run .ipa on simulators. you need .app version of the app , for which you need to contact the developer too

Comment: i created a sample ios app with basic ui controller  and used my apple non developer account to create a build out of it. so the .app i got from that also i had the same problem when trying to run on appium. I guess then i need to sign it with a developer account itself.